# Intellij autocreates xml tags, how can it be disabled?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

I'm with IntelliJ Idea 14.1.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.1
When I open/create a XML file and start writing, after
every space the editor creates a tag with the word before the space.

For example if I write:

```
The
```

After hitting space the editor leaves me with

```
<The></The>
```

with the cursor between the tags.
It is very frustrating and makes the XML editor almost unusable for me.
A have tried to disable all smart keys in Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys and the check boxes in Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion but that doesn't do any help.

How can I disable this 'feature'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ comes with a toolkit called Emmet (see [emmet.io](http://emmet.io)) and it has an option group in Settings -> Editor -> Emmet
There you must entirely disable emmet or just change the expand abbreviation key (which in my case was space).